# Qt program exit blocked in window7 '__scrt_common_main_seh'

Tags: c++, qt

one qt widget program, use threads dynamic dll etc..., this problem is not present on window10,i trace debug on '__scrt_common_main_seh'.

```
if (!__scrt_is_managed_app())
            exit(main_result);//block
```

Comment: At a guess there's an unhandled exception somewhere, please show a [mre]

Comment: According to your reminder, i locate the problem is use spdlog, If I comment it out it works fine，but i donot know why

Comment: If you s show a [mre] we might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

if you do this

```
int main()
{
spdlog::flush_every(std::chrono::seconds(10));//it will create a thread A
...
spdlog::drop_all();
}
//it will delete all instance, one instance like this:
SPDLOG_INLINE registry &registry::instance()
{
    static registry s_instance;
    return s_instance;
}
```

s_instance release timing is after main{}, and A thread join will block exit().
so you should do like this:

```
int main()
{
spdlog::flush_every(std::chrono::seconds(10));//it will create a thread A
...
spdlog::shutdown();//it will release thread A before main{} end;
spdlog::drop_all();
}
```

so static xxx instance is not perfect, we cannot control instance release timing.